# Finder view options "use as defaults" does nothing

Tags: finder, macos, icon

I am using Mac OS X Sierra. I'm trying to disable thumbnail loading in Finder for all folders, since every time I open a folder of PDFs it takes about 2 seconds to load, which I find slow. This seems to happen every time even when I open the same folder, so it appears the Thumbnails are not getting cached.

I went into view options, disabled the thumbnail loading, and clicked "use as defaults". However, it didn't actually apply to all folders. When I go into a different folder, I have to make the setting changes I *just* made again. If I'm not mistaken, this seems to defeat the entire purpose of a "use as defaults" feature, because I'm assuming that's supposed to apply to all folders, so you don't have to painstakingly go to each individual folder and change the settings.

I have the same problem as in [this thread by someone else](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/finder-window-default-preferences-not-working.1720214/) from 2014. The solution in that thread was to make the settings in the top-level folders on the finder sidebar (Documents, Download, etc.) and then clicking "use as defaults", after which the subfolders are supposed to automatically be set. I did this, and the subfolders were not set.

Anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should not do this with a folder in the sidebar: that is only an alias.
Do the same with a folder in the Homefolder and it works:
check the most above views: always open in icon view and browse in icon view

Comment: this does not work for me. I went to my Home folder and double clicked Documents. Then I went to View -> Show view options. "Show Icon Preview" was already unchecked (which is what I want), so I clicked "use as defaults". However, I then navigated to a subfolder of Documents, and icon thumbnail previews were still there. I even looked at Show view options of *this* folder, and the "show icon preview* was actually *checked*. Hence, the "use as defaults" did not work at all.

Comment: At a guess, you might have to trash any existing DS Store files. [Onyx](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html) (freeware) can do that for you. [Don't drop a whole volume on it, you might not want the whole thing cleared.]

Comment: perhaps in older versions of Onyx, they are not visible in Sierra, and it is not in Onyx.

Comment: `sudo find / -name ".DS_Store" -depth -exec rm {} \;`